# How to have an prompt show up in the canvas after input

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a forum program where there is a text limit. When I try to run the code I created it says that text1 is not defined when I clearly defined it above.

```
 def forum():
     mk = Tk()
     canvas = Canvas(mk, width=425, height=425, bg ='grey')
     canvas.pack()
     Labelforum1 = Label(mk, text="Forum", bg='gray', font=('Times', 30))
     Labelforum1.pack()
     Labelforum1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)
     Labelforum2 = Label(mk, text="Name:", bg='gray')
     Labelforum2.pack()
     Labelforum2.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.22, anchor=CENTER)
     Entryforum1 = Entry(mk, bd =5, width=20)
     Entryforum1.pack()
     Entryforum1.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.22, anchor=CENTER)
     Labelforum3 = Label(mk, text="Prompt:", bg='gray')
     Labelforum3.pack()
     Labelforum3.place(relx=0.12, rely=0.33, anchor=CENTER)
     text1 = Text(mk, width=50, height=6)
     text1.pack()
     text1.place(relx=0.49, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
     Buttonforforum = Button(mk, text="Post", bg ='grey', command=begin)
     Buttonforforum.pack()
     Buttonforforum.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.70, anchor=CENTER)
     bfforum = Button(mk, text="Go to message board", command=begin)
     bfforum.pack()
     bfforum.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.86, anchor=CENTER)
     labelc = Label(mk, text="(200 character limit)", bg = 'grey')
     labelc.pack()
     labelc.place(relx=0.19, rely=0.69, anchor=CENTER)

def begin():
    answer = text1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    if len(answer) <= 10:
        label = Label(mk, text="This prompt is being added to the forum")
        label.pack()
        label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor=CENTER)
    else:
        label1 = Label(mk, text="This prompt is too long")
        label1.pack()
        label1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor=CENTER)
```

Why is it giving me this error. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In your code `text1` is a local variable, meaning it is only visible inside `forum`.

Comment: What should I do to have it still appear in the forum but not be a local variable

Comment: make it a global variable.

Comment: how do you create a global variable

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Oakley said in his comment, `text1` is a local variable, so it exists only in the `forum` function. In order to use it in the `begin` function, you need to declare it as a global variable. The same applies to `mk`.

Below is how declare `mk` and `text1` as global variables:

```
def forum():
     global text1, mk
     mk = Tk()
     # ...
```

**EDIT:** Full code that runs without error

```
from tkinter import *

def forum():
    global mk, text1
    mk = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(mk, width=425, height=425, bg ='grey')
    canvas.pack()
    Labelforum1 = Label(mk, text="Forum", bg='gray', font=('Times', 30))
    Labelforum1.pack()
    Labelforum1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)
    Labelforum2 = Label(mk, text="Name:", bg='gray')
    Labelforum2.pack()
    Labelforum2.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.22, anchor=CENTER)
    Entryforum1 = Entry(mk, bd =5, width=20)
    Entryforum1.pack()
    Entryforum1.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.22, anchor=CENTER)
    Labelforum3 = Label(mk, text="Prompt:", bg='gray')
    Labelforum3.pack()
    Labelforum3.place(relx=0.12, rely=0.33, anchor=CENTER)
    text1 = Text(mk, width=50, height=6)
    text1.pack()
    text1.place(relx=0.49, rely=0.50, anchor=CENTER)
    Buttonforforum = Button(mk, text="Post", bg ='grey', command=begin)
    Buttonforforum.pack()
    Buttonforforum.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.70, anchor=CENTER)
    bfforum = Button(mk, text="Go to message board", command=begin)
    bfforum.pack()
    bfforum.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.86, anchor=CENTER)
    labelc = Label(mk, text="(200 character limit)", bg = 'grey')
    labelc.pack()
    labelc.place(relx=0.19, rely=0.69, anchor=CENTER)

def begin():
    answer = text1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    if len(answer) <= 10:
        label = Label(mk, text="This prompt is being added to the forum")
        label.pack()
        label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor=CENTER)
    else:
        label1 = Label(mk, text="This prompt is too long")
        label1.pack()
        label1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor=CENTER)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    forum()
    mk.mainloop()
```

Comment: But when I try to run the code it says text1 isn't defined so I try to make text 1 in the definition(begin). When I try to do that it just makes the text box in a different tk screen rather then the forum one. Do you know how to keep the text box on the forum screen

Comment: I've added the full code I used to test your problem. When I run it, there is no error.

Comment: It doesn't run an error. The text box doesn't show up on the forum screen but rather shows up on a separate tk screen. How could I make the text box appear on the forum screen

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I have only one window when I run your code.

Comment: I only posted a little bit of my program on this post. It is a court booking website and has multiple features so I didn't want to post all the code. There are a 4 or 5 pop up boxes

Comment: I cannot see what's wrong from the code you have posted so I cannot help you further.